# JQuery .focusin event on all input elements not in div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a massive long form with about 40 inputs. I want to listen to all focusin events on input fields except ones inside one div with an ID "CxInfo". Is this possible?

Form (Pseudo-Code)

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="input1" />
<input type="text" name="input2" />
... many more inputs
<div id="CxInfo"> << I want to NOT listen to focusin events on inputs in this div
<input type="text" name="fname" />
<input type="text" name="lname" />
... many more inputs
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation to your `form` element, filtering out events triggered on descendants of `#CxInfo`:

```
$(myform).on('focusin', ':not(#CxInfo input)', function(e) {
    /* Your code here */
});
```

```js
$('#myform').on('focusin', ':not(#CxInfo input)', function(e) {
    this.value = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <input value="foo" />
    <div id="CxInfo">
        <input  value="bar" />
    </div>
    <input value="baz" />
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could stop the propagation of the events triggered inside that element:

```
$('#myform').on('focusin', 'input', function(e) {
    /* Your code here */
});
$('#CxInfo').on('focusin', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
$('#myform').on('focusin', 'input', function(e) {
    this.value = '';
});
$('#CxInfo').on('focusin', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <input value="foo" />
    <div id="CxInfo">
        <input  value="bar" />
    </div>
    <input value="baz" />
</form>
```

Comment: Not working :( 

    $('#Order :text').on('focusin', function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == "CxInfo") return;
        $(this).val("");
    });

Comment: The inputs are inside a div with the id, not the input themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but you could use `$('Form > input'). On(...)` should work as it should only fire for inputs that are a direct child of the form, like your html.